# How to sort a table in Pages?

Tags: macos, pages

Few hours ago I am trying to sort a table! I don't know where is this think but is so annoying that I can't find with ease this thing.

I saw many articles saying that you have to go to Inspector, table tab and there is an option there, but this is the old version, I own the new one 5.5 and there is no such option.

Do you know guys where is this thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the down arrow on the column header and select Sort Ascending or Sort Decending.

Comment: it was so easy! T-H-A-N-K YOU is about 2 hours I am trying to find this! cheers

Comment: Yes- this works! I also had to figure out how to add a new entry in a table. In case someone else did not know: Click to select the last cell at the bottom and click on tab, put in the new entry and then sort per the above instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click anywhere in the table so the row and column designations appear.
2. Put your cursor on the letter of the column you'd like to sort by.
3. Right-click, then select "Sort Ascending" or "Sort Descending"

Answer (score 0):

Apple is no help with this.  I found this wonderful website which does alphabetizing and more: http://alphabetizer.flap.tv

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.